# What's wrong with IIS7 rewrite rule

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect, http-redirect, no-www

I'm trying to do a simple redirect from the www subdomain to the root domain.  After trying many variations, I'm stuck and hoping for help.  Feeling sure it's something stupid, but can't see it.  Here's the rule I'm using.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"  />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.stitchamerica.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://stitchamerica.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://YOURSITE.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: FYI, If you have URL Rewrite installed, you can access it through IIS.  Double click and add rules is the easiest way to write these rules.

Comment: hanks for the answer but your suggestion is not working either.  I copied your code and substituted my domain name but No Bueno. Is there something I'm missing?  Some setting in IIS7 that is overriding?

Comment: This is an MVC application.  Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Interesting, I can use that to redirect to www., but not to remove it.  I will need to research this some more.

Comment: Okay, I think that should work.  I had to change the match url and condition pattern.

Comment: Wow, thanks again but that's not working either.  I installed the URL Rewrite module and set up a rule that also did not work.  Screenshot attached below.  Was hoping to avoid by setup Trace Failed request on web.config to get more information.  Were you able to verify your suggestion above?

Comment: Based on the rule testing in the URL Rewrite Module the URL noted would have resulted in double slashes so also tried:  http://yourdomain{r:1} to no avail.

Comment: The pattern is wrong. You should be able to copy what I have into your config file and only replace the YOURSITE part.

Comment: My bad!  I was editing a web.config file on my desktop but then uploading the file in the project (which wasn't changed).  Thanks again for your help.  It works just fine when I got the right code uploaded EXCEPT it always redirects to the root and leaves off any of the request.  Looks like there should be another variable on the end.

Comment: So the URL needs to have the variable {R:0} concatenated onto it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't include {R:0}, because my site didn't need it.  I have added it to the answer to those who come across this.